# Python - List comprehension with multiple arguments in the for

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have this current list comprehension:

```
...
cur = [[14, k, j] for j, k in rows[14], range(15)]
...
```

and it is giving me the following error:

```
...        
    cur = [[14, k, j] for j, k in rows[14], range(15)]
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Any help appreciated as in how I would fix this. I just don't want to have to write out a full for loop or the entire list by hand. Thank you! :D

**Extra info:**

```
rows = [{1: '75'},
        {1: '95', 2: '64'}, 
        {1: '17', 2: '47', 3: '82'}, 
        {1: '18', 2: '35', 3: '87', 4: '10'}, 
        {1: '20', 2: '04', 3: '82', 4: '47', 5: '65'}, 
        {1: '19', 2: '01', 3: '23', 4: '75', 5: '03', 6: '34'}, 
        {1: '88', 2: '02', 3: '77', 4: '73', 5: '07', 6: '63', 7: '67'}, 
        {1: '99', 2: '65', 3: '04', 4: '28', 5: '06', 6: '16', 7: '70', 8: '92'}, 
        {1: '41', 2: '41', 3: '26', 4: '56', 5: '83', 6: '40', 7: '80', 8: '70', 9: '33'}, 
        {1: '41', 2: '48', 3: '72', 4: '33', 5: '47', 6: '32', 7: '37', 8: '16', 9: '94', 10: '29'}, 
        {1: '53', 2: '71', 3: '44', 4: '65', 5: '25', 6: '43', 7: '91', 8: '52', 9: '97', 10: '51', 11: '14'}, 
        {1: '70', 2: '11', 3: '33', 4: '28', 5: '77', 6: '73', 7: '17', 8: '78', 9: '39', 10: '68', 11: '17', 12: '57'}, 
        {1: '91', 2: '71', 3: '52', 4: '38', 5: '17', 6: '14', 7: '91', 8: '43', 9: '58', 10: '50', 11: '27', 12: '29', 13: '48'}, 
        {1: '63', 2: '66', 3: '04', 4: '68', 5: '89', 6: '53', 7: '67', 8: '30', 9: '73', 10: '16', 11: '69', 12: '87', 13: '40', 14: '31'}, 
        {1: '04', 2: '62', 3: '98', 4: '27', 5: '23', 6: '09', 7: '70', 8: '98', 9: '73', 10: '93', 11: '38', 12: '53', 13: '60', 14: '04', 15: '23'}]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) them to iterate like that:

```
cur = [[14, k, j] for j, k in zip(rows[14], range(15))]
```

Comment: What exactly is zipping? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @EthanBrouwer I linked it, basically you can only iterate through a single iterable in a `for` loop, to iterate two at a time, you need to use `zip` which produces an iterable that returns a tuple of the corresponding items at each index from the lists.

Comment: Does that mean I also have to put (j, k) or does that not matter?

Comment: @EthanBrouwer You don't have to, and when iterating like this it's stylistically preferable not to.

Comment: To understand this frithfully cryptic code, you have to understand that 1/ zip accepts iterables as parameters and 2/ that iterating over a dictionary returns only the key.

Comment: @Jean-PierreSchnyder This code is just helping out the OP to fix his attempt. Maybe if i was approaching it from scratch I would do the whole thing differently. However 1/ everyone already knows zip accepts itterables as parameters and 2/ it is pythonic to take advantage of the fact that iterating a dictionary iterates the keys

Answer (score 5):

To explain your code:

```
cur = [[14, k, j] for j, k in rows[14], range(15)]
```

is the same as:

```
cur = [[14, k, j] for j, k in (rows[14], range(15))]
```

Now, we see more clearly that you've created a `tuple` and are iterating over it.  The first time through the loop, the tuple gives up `rows[14]` which is a dictionary that has more than 2 items in it, so it can't be unpacked into `j` and `k`.

As noted by `jamylak`, the key is to `zip` the two iterables together.

```
cur = [[14, k, j] for j,k in zip(rows[14],range(15))]
```

You can think of it like a zipper:

```
zip(a,b) = [
   (a[0], b[0]),
   (a[1], b[1]),
   (a[2], b[2]),
   ...
   }
```

written out this way, you see how the structure sort of resembles a zipper (with `a` and `b` being the left and right pieces of the zipper.  After you zipping, you've matched an element on the left with an element on the right.  Of course, the objects you pass to `zip` don't need to be indexable (All that matters is that you can iterate over them), and you can "zip" more than 2 iterables together ...

Comment: `rows[14]` is the final `dictionary` in the rows `list`

Comment: @EthanBrouwer -- Thanks.  That helps (I guess I should have read more carefully)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @jamylak's answer: Alternatively you can use map

```
cur = [[14, k, j] for j, k in map(None,rows[14], range(15))]
```

This will pad the shorter lists with None.

Comment: `itertools.izip_longest` is the better way to do that

Comment: @mgilson oh no! edit: wait no it hasn't, only the `None` thing

Comment: @jamylak -- Correction.  Calling `map` with `None` goes away in python3.x